# Ajuda para importar dado SQL e usar na data

Tags: php

O título está muito baralhado mas não sei o que quero fazer.

Dentro de uma tabela com dados que veem do  banco de dados
Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
echo '<tr><td> '.$row["data"].'</td></tr>';
```

Até aqui tudo bem, aparece as varias datas  na tabela. Agora
Preciso de usar o valor que vem da data para usar outro código ex:

```
$dataextenco = '.$row["data"].';

// Transformar a data que vem do BD em dia da semana

// Tabela

echo '<tr><td> '.$row["data"].'</td></tr>';
```

Desculpem por estar muito baralhado, mas não consigo explicar melhor e aqui não tenho o código completo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo Vitor! Meu caro colega, você disse que não sabe o que quer fazer, não consegue explicar e não tem o código! Se nem você está sabendo e possui nada, imagine nós!? rs Precisa melhor a pergunta, se não é impossível ajudarmos algo que nem mesmo você sabe nos passar.

Comment: Sem informação eu sei que e difícil.

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar colocar aqui um printscren

Comment: Vitor, não é por nada não, mas sem condições de andar com sua pergunta dessa forma. Se eu continuar ajudando estarei aprovando a "má qualidade" e isso está errado. Peço que leia ao menos o [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Assim podemos continuar.

Comment: Se você tem o código, simplesmente copie e cole aqui, era até mais fácil que tirar foto! Além de estar atropelando tudo. Não adianta pegar um código e ir alterando sem ao menos entender o que ele faz. É complicado para ambos. Aqui ajudamos com dúvidas, não a fazer códigos. Tomara que entenda o que eu quis dizer... ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Imprimindo o dia da semana:

```
 // Array com os dias da semana
 $diasemana = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado');

 // Aqui define a data no formato Ano-mês-dia (2018-09-11)
 $data = $row["data"];

 // Varivel que recebe o dia da semana (0 = Domingo, 1 = Segunda ...)
 $diasemana_numero = date('w', strtotime($data));

 // Exibe o dia da semana
 echo $diasemana[$diasemana_numero];
```

---

#### Referência

[Dia da Semana em PHP](http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/dia-da-semana-em-php)